Running into 500 deadline exceeded errors in a cross-service GRPC request
I'm dealing with one of the hardest bugs of my career. To start with a brief summary: I have two services, both written in python. The first (henceforth referred to asclient), is an http-serving API client. It calls the second (henceforth referred to as server), which is a python GRPC service.
The behavior I'm seeing is very strange. I have written effectively a no-op endpoint in server. If make 20 HTTP requests toclient, the first 5-10 requests will succeed -- then the service will lock up and start returning 500 deadline exceeded errors indefinitely. The timeout is almost certainly not legitimate -- client is basically just immediately returning. When the call succeeds it takes less than half a second, and when it fails it's more like 7 seconds.
What makes the problem stranger is how unreproducible it is when calling server in other ways. Running in a python shell in client, I can execute a for loop 500 times and get no errors -- even passing the exact same headers that client is passing. Calling GRPCurl from client or other services works fine. In my dev environment (which is ostensibly identical) the behavior is not reproducible.
Both these services use gevent, but I think I've escaped those problems -- both services call
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

Server also calls grpc_gevent.init_gevent()
I've tried playing around with a bunch of timeout parameters in the hope that possibly killing connections more quickly may alleviate the problem, but no luck so far.
It also probably goes without saying, but there's nothing in the logs. Sometimes the requests are reaching server after the lockup, but sometimes they aren't. There's no obvious error or any indication of what's going wrong
Most of the things I've tried have been trying to repro the problem in easier-to-iterate ways, but so far I've had no luck.

localdev doesn't repro
GRPCurl doesn't repro
emulating the headers doesn't repro
calling from client to server while kubectl'd into client doesn't repro

I'd expect all of these things to behave the same, but clearly I'm missing something! Any directional vectors for where to explore next would be much appreciated. I'm somewhat out of ideas.
